# How to sign-in from code behind in abp.io?

Tags: rest, aspnetboilerplate, boilerplate, abp, asp.net-boilerplate

I am exploring the abp.io and trying to develop a vary simple test-app. Currently, I've exposed a restful api which users could use it to create a new account using only the mobile phone number. The next step is to sign-in from C# and return token to api-caller.

How can I sign-in from C#? Is there any sign-in service (like SignInManager) or restful api for login purpose?

P.S. I found the solution and it's all about including a module in abp.io, read more about the solution in comments.

Comment: I've found a page which you can customize the SignInManager, but I'm wondering if there's a rest-api or service already in abp.io for sign-in purpose.
Documentation url: 
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/2.9/How-To/Customize-SignIn-Manager

Comment: Finally,  I found the solution from abp.io's official GitHub repository, To add login/logout api to current project, two steps are needed, first, install package "Volo.Abp.Account.Web.IdentityServer" on YourProjectName.HttpApi.Host project, second, include AbpAccountWebIdentityServerModule in YourProjectName.HttpApi.Host.YourProjectNameHttpApiHostModule.cs

Comment: If you've faced with any problem, please don't hesitate to ask. thanks to StackOverFlow and users.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an `IRemoteServiceHttpClientAuthenticator` and an `AccessTokenManager` and inject both of them. follow this article :

https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/53/Login-From-Desktop-Client